# How to show the bar for small values in python chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib.pyplot` to draw a bar graph from csv files. The graph is drawn successfully.
I am plotting some values on X axis. However, when I have for example this data:

```
A = 10
B = 2000,000
```

The A bar does not appear on the graph because its value is too small. I need to show A bar even if it is too small, what should I do?
What is the method that should I change its value?

I used the following:

```
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(axis='x')
plt.grid(which='minor',axis='x',linestyle=':',linewidth=0.6)
```

Comment: Change to log scale?

Comment: Yes, but how could I do that? when the data are A = 10 and B= 1000 all bar are showed. But, when the scale is large , i.e B=2000,000 the A does not show the bar.